# MySQL n to m relationship select confusion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a n to many relationship. A student can have multiple majors and a major can include multiple students. Studentwithid_1 and Studentwithid_2 has two majors and Studentwithid_3 has one major.

student table:

[image]

Major table:

[image]

And the student_has_major_table:

[image]

Suppose I want to select all the majors that Studentwithid_1 have, how should I run the code?

```
select major.name from major join student where student.id=1
```

Above is what I tried but it is not working, I am new to MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the student_has_major table too

```
SELECT major.name FROM major
JOIN student_has_major_table ON student_has_major_table.major_id = major.id
JOIN student ON student.id = student_has_major_table.student_id
WHERE student.id=1
```

Comment: If i did not join the student table and use the student_id in the where clause, that is also ok?

Comment: If you only need the Majors data by student id then yes, the where clause will be "WHERE student_has_major_table.student_id=1", but if you need the student's data and their Majors data you will need to join all 3 tables